# Boot fails with "Loading initial ramdisk ..."

Tags: 14.04, boot, crash

I urgently need help with this here!

4 years old server.
Ubuntu 14.04 server i686.
Linux 3.13.0-149-generic was the last version to run flawlessly.
10 days ago, I upgraded to 3.13.0.151.
Server crashes then on boot.

Screen shows ...

```
Loading Linux 3.13.0-151-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
```

1 second later ... reboot.

Same with 3.13.0-151 recovery mode.
Same with 3.13.0-153 (most recent as of today, normal and recovery mode).

**How can I find out**, after subsequent successful 3.13.0-149 bootup, **what exactly generates the crash**?

Thanks!

----- later -----

@heynnema tried to help me out by telling me how to construct a new `initrd.img-*` for 151 (`update-initramfs -c -k 3.13.0-151-generic`). See below. This didn't work. 151 still didn't make the system boot. My fatal mistake was then to say `update-initramfs -c -k 3.13.0-149-generic` (the only working kernel). After that, I was stuck. No kernel to boot from anymore! Same probem with ramdisk as for 151 and 153.

After that, I started a Live DVD (`ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-i386.iso`) on the stuck system, mounted an old 14.05.5 VM with 3.13 kernels on another computer, updated these (`apt-get dist-upgrade`), copied the resulting `initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic` (latest kernel) to the stuck system ('/boot') and the it booted again (with 153)! This was to my big surprise, not knowing that the `initrd.img-*` from a VM would work on a real hardware! However I was still unable to boot from 149 and 151 (which makes sense).

All of the above was just to get the system up and working again. The problem itself is not solved!

Bottomline:
`update-initramfs` uses data (files) on the system to build `initrd.img-*`. On my box, this makes it impossible to get further than "Loading initial ramdisk ...".

Questions:
Which files are used by `update-initramfs`?
Can I (?!) do something to create a build again a working `initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic`?

As long as this problem is not solved, future built `initrd-img-*` files will almost certainly also crash!

Comment: Boot into -149 and in `terminal` type `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 3.13.0-151`, then reboot to -151, and see if that fixes the problem. Report back to @heynnema.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I feel safer to wait until 4.15.0-24 has a fix, hoping that it will be implemented as well in 3.13.0-151. Meanwhile, I changed grub that it keeps on booting from 3.13.0-149.

Comment: You're running 3.13... not 4.15. My command will do no harm, and might easily fix your problem with -151 and -153. Please begin comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema - `update-initramfs -c -k 3.13.0-151-generic` didn't work. Actually no surprise since `/boot/config-3.13.0-*-generic` (all 3 config files - 149, 151 and 153) don't show any differences (except version numbers).

Comment: You lost me. What does "config-anything" have to do with my **update-initramfs" command?

Comment: @heynnema - Typo at my end. I forgot to post the first part of the command. I corrected the comment above!

Comment: @heynnema - Now, the system doen't boot anymore. Not even from 149. Well ... thanks a lot!

Comment: That wasn't very nice. There may be something more wrong with your system. Try booting -149 in recovery mode, or try booting an earlier -14x kernel, if you have one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79800/discussion-between-geohei-and-heynnema).

Comment: Maybe `lsinitramfs <initramfsfile>` will show what you want to see.

Comment: this helped me https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/fixing-broken-initrd-image-linux/ in a similar situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Again an idea from @heynnema (thanks!)

`lsinitramfs` didn't work on all 3 non-working `initrd.img` files (149, 151, 153).

```
root@gan:~# lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153
/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153

gzip: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153: not in gzip format
cpio: premature end of archive
```

Then this here this morning ...

```
root@gan:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-151 linux-headers-3.13.0-151-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-151-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-151-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  amd64-microcode
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 26.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64-microcode i386 3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.14.04.2+really20130710.1 [26.3 kB]
Fetched 26.3 kB in 0s (387 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 132952 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../amd64-microcode_3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.14.04.2+really20130710.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking amd64-microcode (3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.14.04.2+really20130710.1) over (3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up amd64-microcode (3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.14.04.2+really20130710.1) ...
Updating microcode on all online processors...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu4.11) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
```

Booting worked again !!!

`lsinitramfs` now as well!

```
root@gan:~# lsinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
.
sbin
sbin/biosdevname
...
```

Updated other `initrd.img` files also (149 and 151).

```
root@gan:/boot# update-initramfs -c -k 3.13.0-151-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-151-generic
root@gan:/boot# update-initramfs -c -k 3.13.0-149-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-149-generic
```

All 3 were accepted now by `lsinitranfs`.
All 3 could be used for booting.

Hence, the source of the issue was `amd64-microcode`. This took 2 weeks for a fix to appear.

For testing purpose, I manually built `initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic` using `update-initramfs`. The result was not exactly the same as the one built by `apt-get update`, but it worked as well.

Thanks for all the help!